# Ember-Data Transformed Value not Updated With Bindings

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Here is my transformer:

```
DS.attr.transforms.category = {
    from: function(serialized) {
        return OO.Category.create({
            tag: serialized
        });
    },

    to: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized.get('tag');
    }
}
```

And my model:

```
OO.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    category: DS.attr('category', { key: 'tag' })
}
```

When I bring up the form for creating an OO.Event, I create a "blank" OO.Event and bind the form element to the OO.Event's properties. The transformer is called when the blank OO.Event is created, but it is not called again when the tag property of the OO.Category changes (due to bindings.) Because of this, in the JSON representation of the record, "tag" is always null!

What should I do? Thanks for your help!